# Running Frozen Tensorflow model on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm new to tensorflowjs (and js in general), however I need to run a trained model on it.
Currently I converted the model to json format, but struggle to feed data to it:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs')
const tfn = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu')

async function start() { 
    const handler = tfn.io.fileSystem("./model/model.json"); 
    const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(handler); 
    let latents = tf.randomNormal([1,512], 'float32'); 
    let labels = tf.zeros([1, 0]); 
    model.predict([latents, labels]);
}
start();
```

But I receive an error saying `The Conv2D op currently supports NHWC tensor format on the CPU. The op was given the format: NCHW`

So as I understood, it is a tfjs issue, so I tried to create a float32 array and pass it to model like this:

```
var f32array = new Float32Array(512);
model.predict([f32array, labels]);
```

But then I see an error saying `the dtype of dict['Gs/latents_in'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be float32, but was undefined`

With python, I'm running inference by using this code:

```
graph = load_graph("dash/frozen_model.pb")

    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/Gs/latents_in:0')
    x2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/Gs/labels_in:0')
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/Gs/images_out:0')


    with tf.Session(graph=graph, config = config) as sess:
        while True:
            start_time = time.time()

            latents = np.random.randn(1, 512).astype(np.float32)
            labels = np.zeros([latents.shape[0], 0], np.float32)
            y_out = sess.run(y, feed_dict = { x: latents, x2: labels})
```

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Passing the data as `Float32Array` will not work since `model.predict` expects either a tensor or an array of tensors.

As indicated by the error:

> The Conv2D op currently supports NHWC tensor format on the CPU. The op was given the format: NCHW

the conv2D as of the version `1.6` in js only supports the format NHWC. The only thing you can do is to change the model in python in order to use only the NHWC format.

Comment: that's what I thought I'll have to do, thanks for the answer